# MySQL error 1045 after grant, what did I do wrong?

Tags: mysql

I entered the following:

```
mysql> grant all on DBNAME.* to 'root@localhost' identified by 'MYROOTPWD';
```

Then I quit out of mysql and did some shell stuff. Now when I try to use mysql it fails with

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm not mistyping the password; I can see it in the grant command a few lines up in my terminal. I've tried a bunch of the [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+grant+root+error+1045) on this topic without success.

What did I do wrong? Sure, I can reset the root password and move on, but I want to know my mistake so I never repeat it.

UPDATE: No, I didn't flush privileges. Apparently I have misunderstood what that does. Why is my previously-existing ability (to use mysql at all) not working?

Comment: Did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` ??

Comment: Did you execute FLUSH PRIVILEGES after you issue the grant?

Comment: Note that the `GRANT` statement automatically does the appropriate equivalent to the "flush privilege" operation; the privilege tables are read when GRANT, REVOKE, SET PASSWORD statements are performed. The `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` statement is needed when DML changes are made  directly to the privilege tables; those changes aren't notice, and are not in effect, until MySQL reads the privileges tables again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL user should be identified by separate username and hostname, in the GRANT statement:

```
> grant ... to 'root'@'localhost' ...
                    ^ ^
```

(Note the quotes around the username and around the hostname.) A MySQL user is identified by username and a hostname. If you just have a single quoted string, MySQL uses that as a the username and assumes a hostname.  Check the mysql.db table, likely you have a row with `User` column containing `root@localhost`.

Comment: Okay, I can log in with -u root@localhost, who doesn't have permission to do anything with the mysql db.

Comment: But I still don't understand what happened to root. Did this new user overwrite it?

Comment: It's unlikely that the GRANT statement "overwrote" any user. A MySQL user is identified by two values: `username` and `hostname`; and there's some funkiness with hostname of `'localhost'`; that's not a normal TCP 127.0.0.1 loopback. (The `'%'` wildcard in the `hostname` will match if another row in mysql.user doesn't match.) On the plus side, you are *not* the only one to have these kinds of issues. MySQL documentation has a section which you may find useful [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html).